# Which watchface uses CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularView?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-complication

Is there a documentation/web page on which Apple Watch watch faces uses which complication types?

I am trying to find which watch face uses CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularView. This is a rare SwiftUI view and I have been trying to find a watch face to test it.

According to documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationtemplategraphicextralargecircularview), the watch face looks like this (but what is this):
[image: Watch Face]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: it is the X-Large watch face.
The main reason why I can't find it initially is: without complication, this watch face does not look like this (just 2 rows of big text). Only when added complications it looks like the above.